# Program type already present

Tags: angular, apk, ionic

При компиляции проекта в APK выдает ошибку:

```
Program type already present: com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat
```

Вся проблема в установленном плагине `phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`, если  его удалить, то APK собирается, но при этом не работает сканер. Без этого модуля никак, т.к. его требует [`ionic-native/barcode-scanner`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner). 
Может кто сталкивался? Куда копать?

`package.json`:

```
    {
      "name": "dg2019",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "author": "Ionic Framework",
      "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "2gis-maps": "^3.5.8",
        "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
        "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
        "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
        "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
        "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
        "@ionic-native/app-availability": "^5.10.0",
        "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.5.1",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^5.10.0",
        "@ionic-native/device": "^5.5.1",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^5.10.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.5.1",
        "@ionic-native/http": "^5.10.0",
        "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.5.1",
        "@ionic-native/market": "^5.10.0",
        "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.10.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
        "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^3.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.1.1",
        "cordova-plugin-appavailability": "^0.4.2",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-market": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
        "ionic-cordova-oauth": "0.0.9",
        "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.0.1",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.13.8",
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.8",
        "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.3.8",
        "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.3.8",
        "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
        "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.5.1",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~12.0.0",
        "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~5.17.0",
        "typescript": "~3.1.6"
      },
      "description": "An Ionic project",
      "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
          "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
          "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
          "cordova-plugin-device": {},
          "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
          "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
            "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
          },
          "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
          "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
          "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {
            "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.10.0"
          },
          "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
          "cordova-plugin-appavailability": {},
          "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
            "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
          },
          "cordova-plugin-market": {},
          "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
            "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
          }
        },
        "platforms": [
          "android"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, дело было в минорной версии ionic, обновился с 5.2.2 на 5.2.3 и ошибка пропала